# PostgreSQL Import Tool (RDF/JSON/CSV)

Tags: json, postgresql, import, rdf

I'm looking for a (GUI) tool that helps me converting various data formats (mostly RDF, JSON and CSV) into a PostgreSQL database.
Is there any nice tool that helps me defining the table schema for the files I want to import (and interlink) and to import the data?

Comment: Short version: I doubt it, not PostgreSQL specific at least. I'm sure there are database-agnostic database design and ETL/data loader tools out there that can help but I expect most are $lots. On the loading side check out Talend Studio and Pentaho Kettle.

Comment: [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) may at least help you convert the three formats to one.

Answer (score 1):

One. You can try to link the tables in Microsoft Access with pgODBC
2nd. You can import files. Csv into Access and run commands Insert
3rd. Click the file through Access to Export and choose the PostgreSQL ODBC source you want.